# how to check all of the first and second elements of the 2D array?

Tags: c#, arrays

how should I write this N ?

```
 int[,] spn = { { 3064, 22 }, { 3064, 16 }, { 3064, 11 } };

 if(spn[1, N] != 3064 && spn[N, 2] != 16 || spn[N, 2] != 16)
```

spn[1, N] means all of the first items of the array.
spn[N, 2] means all of the second items of the array.

Comment: can you also add the expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over the array with a for loop ([MSDN for (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ch45axte.aspx)

```
      int[,] spn = { { 3064, 22 }, { 3064, 16 }, { 3064, 11 } };
      int helper = 2;
      for (var N = 0; N < spn.Length / helper; N++)
      {
          if (spn[N, 0] != 3064 && spn[N, 1] != 16 || spn[N, 1] != 16)
              System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("do something");
      }
```

As the array has only a absolute length, you save the number of arrayelements inside the helper variable. This only works for your sample with nested arrays of the same length.

Answer (score 0):

You can you simple Loop:

```
 bool result = true;
 for (int i = 0; i < spn.GetLength(0); i++)
 {
    if (spn[i, 1] != 16 || spn[i, 2] != 16)
    {
       result = false;
       break;
    }
 }
```

Or you can use Linq to check all values:

```
bool result = Enumerable.Range(0, spn.GetLength(0)).All(i => spn[i, 1] != 16 || spn[i, 2] != 16);
```